# How to make my website running on IIS accessible from the web

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2

I am working on setting up a website using an ec2 Windows Server . I set up IIS and I bound my private IP address and port 3000. I am able to reach the site locally on the server. I allowed port 3000 in the AWS console for this instance and I allowed port 3000 in Windows Defender Firewall. But I am getting a 'Service Unavailable' error when trying to connect to the bound IP address at port 3000. Can someone please help me troubleshoot? Thanks!

Comment: You might receive a better response at: https://serverfault.com/

Comment: What do you mean by "allowed port 3000 in the AWS console"? Can you show us what you did?

Comment: It is impossible to analyze the problem based on these simple descriptions alone, please check for more detailed error information.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I was using the private url instead of the public url to connect. Once I changed that it worked.

Comment: If you can mark your answer, it will lead more people in the right direction.